# Data Factory Projects and msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2015, continuous-integration, teamcity, azure-data-factory

Trying to setup CI for a MS Data Factory project. Running fully patched VS2015 with Data Factory Tools for VS installed, using Teamcity 2017.1.2. I've tried running with both the Visual Studio 2015 step and the Msbuild step in TeamCity with the appropriate versions without any luck. I'm running the agent under the same user account, as I login and start VS

I can start VS on the agent and build successfully. If I use TC og the developer prompt I get the following error. Any got dfproj projects to build successfully with msbuild?

> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataFactory Tools for
>   Visual Studio\MsBuild\1.0\DataFactory.targets( 35,5): error MSB4062:
>   The
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DataFactoryStudio.DataFactoryProject.ProjectSystem.ADFCompilerTask"
>   t ask could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\rj
>   paw4at.rk4\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DataFactoryStudio.DataFactoryProject.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft. VisualStudio.Shell.12.0,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies . The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - ended up just building the project with devenv instead and setting up vs environment variables. Feels like Microsoft is stalling on this plugin (and support for vs2017!!) for Data Factory Tools 2.0 instead.

```
pushd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools'    
cmd /c "vsvars32.bat&set" |
foreach {
  if ($_ -match "=") {
    $v = $_.split("="); set-item -force -path "ENV:\$($v[0])"  -value "$($v[1])"
  }
}
popd
write-host "`nVisual Studio 2015 Command Prompt variables set." -ForegroundColor Yellow

devenv somesolution.sln /build "Release|x86"devenv agpdatafactory.sln /build "Release|x86"
```